# Android listview refresh with blink

Tags: android, listview

i have a `listview` data come from server its working fine bu when `listview` refresh its blink how to made it `listview` did not blink.
here is my code of `listview`. i used handler for refresh `listview`.

```
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    personList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            DataSendActivity.this, personList, R.layout.layout_chat,
            new String[]{TAG_DATA, TAG_CREATED_AT},
            new int[]{R.id.data, R.id.created}
    );
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

   final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed( new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //showList();
            isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
            if (isInternetPresent) {
                personList.clear();
                try{
                    getData();
                }catch (Exception e){}

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                list.invalidateViews();
            } else {
                showAlertDialog(DataSendActivity.this, "No Internet Connection",
                        "You don't have internet connection.", false);
            }

            //list.refreshDrawableState();
            handler.postDelayed( this, 8000 );
        }
    }, 8000 );
```

here is the function which show data.

```
    protected void showList() {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
            peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

            for (int i = 0; i < peoples.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);
                String data = c.getString(TAG_DATA);
                String created_at = c.getString(TAG_CREATED_AT);
// final String dataaaa = rcdata.getText().toString().trim();
                HashMap<String, String> user_data = new HashMap<String, String>();
                user_data.put(TAG_DATA, data);
                user_data.put(TAG_CREATED_AT, created_at);


                personList.add(user_data);

            }
            try{
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }catch (Exception e){

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

this is getdata code.

```
public void getData() {
    class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        //String recID = ;
        //String userID = email;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
            HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();

            //String name = user.get("name");
           // Semail = user.get("email");

            String semail  = user.get("email");
            final String remail = rremail;

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://samplechatapp.gear.host/myphpfile.php?sender_email="+semail+"&reciver_email="+remail+"&fatch_server_data=true");

            // Depends on your web service
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            String result = null;
            Log.i("","processing entity");
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                inputStream = entity.getContent();
                // json is UTF-8 by default
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                    Log.i("",line);
                }
                result = sb.toString();
                Log.i("",result);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Oops
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (inputStream != null) inputStream.close();
                } catch (Exception squish) {
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            myJSON = result;
            showList();
        }
    }
    GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
    g.execute();
}
```

listview working fine but problem is this when listview refresh its blink i want listview refresh without blinking. thanks in advance

Comment: What do mean by blink ?

Comment: you just replaced all your items, I think that is why it `blink`. add a animation, my suggestion.

Comment: how to add animation?

Comment: @JiangYD how to use?

Answer (score 1):

`list.invalidateViews();` - for what this? it will redraw views - possible blink coz of this.

`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` - this better call on ui thread runOnUIThread

after you updated list that U attached to adaptor you need only call
`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Here:

```
personList.clear();
try{
    getData();
}catch (Exception e){}
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
list.invalidateViews();
```

notify and invalidate is called before data is loaded, coz you are started asynctask, so u are updating listview before data is loaded

Comment: thats why i used handler

Comment: ist.invalidateViews(); if i dont use it app crash

Comment: when scroll the listview app crash

Comment: thats wyy i use ist.invalidateViews();

Comment: it cannot blink coz of this, it blinks coz of list.invalidateViews(); steps to do initialize list, then attach to adaptor, then attach adaptor to view, then load data, then add data to list, then make adapter notifydatasetchanged that's all, no need to call invalidateviews - coz this redraws your list. Dont insert your listview into scrollview.

Comment: i remove it list.invalidateViews(); but list again blinking

Comment: it's hard to edit your code, coz of bad style :) first use Volley lib for requests, then for deserialization use gson. Create models of data to deserialization to finally after request you got json string, then in async task with gson deserialise to model then pass ready model to your adapter list and only then make notifydatachanged on array, all before notifydatachanged must be async.